# A random variable $X$ on $(0,\infty)$ which behaves like Exp for small $x$ and Pareto for large $x$

Tags: power-law, pareto-distribution, heavy-tailed

Are there any examples of distributions which behave like Exponential for small values and like Pareto for large values. 
$$\ln \mathbb{P}[X>x] \sim -\lambda x, \qquad \text{ for } x \text{ small}, $$
$$\ln \mathbb{P}[X>x] \sim  -\alpha \ln x, \qquad \text{ for } x \text{ large}.$$
I can form a weighted sum of Exp and Pareto. But my question is whether there are any standard distributions that have this behaviour.

When I plot the data I have, I observe linearity for small $x$ in the plot $\quad\ln \mathbb{P}[X>x]\,\, vs\,\, x$, and I observe linearity for large $x$ in the plot $\quad \ln \mathbb{P}[X>x] \,\,vs\, \ln x$.

Comment: Which $x$ values do you relate as small ones?

Comment: If you have linearity in the plot $\ln \text{Prob}[X>x]$ for small $x$ and then again for higher $x$ but with a smaller slope, then it is likely that the underlying distribution is a mixed exponential: $f(x)= p \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x} + (1-p) \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no such 'standard' distribution, but perhaps it is useful to note that the Pareto distribution already looks quite exponential for small $x$. Let's take the Pareto distributed $X$ with density
$$
  f(x)=\alpha (x+1)^{-\alpha-1}\,,\qquad x\geqslant 0\,.
$$
and $\text{Prob}[X\geqslant x] = (x+1)^{\alpha}$. The $n$th derivative in $x=0$ is 
$$
  f^{(n)}(0) = (-1)^n \alpha (\alpha+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(\alpha+n-1)\,,
$$
while the density $g(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ of the exponential distribution has
$$
  g^{(n)}(0) = (-1)^n \lambda^n\,.
$$
For $\alpha$ not too small, the Pareto distribution should therefore behave quite similar as an exponential with $\lambda=\alpha$. If the match is not close enough, then perhaps a weighted density is indeed in order.